# Schedule a DAG in airflow to run every 5 minutes

Tags: airflow

I have a DAG in airflow and for now it is running each hour (@hourly).
Is it possible to have it running each 5 minutes ?

Answer (score 43):

Yes, here's an example of a DAG that I have running every 5 min:

```
dag = DAG(dag_id='eth_rates',
          default_args=args,
          schedule_interval='*/5 * * * *',
          dagrun_timeout=timedelta(seconds=5))
```

`schedule_interval` accepts a CRON expression: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression

Answer (score 4):

Airflow 2 (I'm using 2.4.2) [supports timedelta for scheduling DAGs](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/scheduling-in-airflow) on a particular cadence (hourly, every 5 minutes, etc.) so you can put:

```
schedule_interval = timedelta(minutes=5)
```

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation states](http://pythonhosted.org/airflow/scheduler.html#dag-runs):

> Each DAG may or may not have a schedule, which informs how DAG Runs
>   are created. schedule_interval is defined as a DAG arguments, and
>   receives preferably a cron expression as a str, or a
>   datetime.timedelta object.

When following the provided [link for CRON expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression) it appears you can specify it as `*/5 * * * *` to run it every 5 minutes.

I'm not familiar on the matter, but this is what the documentation states.

Comment: 5 0 0 0 0 is invalid. I think you mean */5 * * * *